# JQuery string replace specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

i'm not good with regex. I need to remove specific characters from an input field on the field.
Say I want to remove "B, C, &, !, @, 0, 1". I use  this code:

```
$('.classInput).on('input', function () {
        var myStr = $(this).val();
        myStr = myStr.replace("B", "");
        myStr = myStr.replace("C", "");
        myStr = myStr.replace("&", "");
        myStr = myStr.replace("!", "");
        myStr = myStr.replace("@", "");
        myStr = myStr.replace("0", "");
        myStr = myStr.replace("1", "");

        $(this).val(myStr.toUpperCase());
    });
```

However I suspect there is a better way of doing this with a regex call?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Use a character class in regex.

```
myStr = myStr.replace(/[BC&!@01]/g,"");
```

But, your jquery is a bit crazy. Correct it ;)